# Insert .xls DataFrame to SQL Table using Python

Tags: sql-server, excel, python-3.8

I am trying to insert a Python dataframe taken from an .xls file, into an existing table in SQL Server Management Studio importing pandas and pyodbc libraries. However I have the following error:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Python/Task1.py", line 27, in 
cursor.execute('''
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure
call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 16 (""): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type float. Check the source data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type with scale greater than precision. (8023) (SQLExecDirectW)')**

Here is my Python script:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

#Import the CSV File into the DataFrame

data = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\Diego\Documents\1.Laboral\Jas-Ole\Revenue Management\Reservation_stats_REF.xls')   
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Confirmation_number','Status','Name','Telephone','Adults','Children','Baby',
'Start_date','End_date','Stays','Reservation_date','Property','Covid_payment','Charged_amount','Revenue','Email',
'Origin','Market_code','Transport'])

#Connect Python to SQL Server

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=DIEGO\SQLEXPRESS;'
                      'Database=Auxiliary;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()

#Delete a Table data in SQL Server using Python
for row in df.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('''
                DELETE FROM Auxiliary.dbo.Res_statsTEMP
                ''')

#Insert DataFrame to Table
for row in df.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO Auxiliary.dbo.Res_statsTEMP (Confirmation_number,Status,Name,Telephone,Adults,
                Children,Baby,Start_date,End_date,Stays,Reservation_date,Property,Covid_payment,Charged_amount,
                Revenue,Email,Origin,Market_code,Transport)
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                ''',
                row.Confirmation_number,
                row.Status,
                row.Name,
                row.Telephone,
                row.Adults,
                row.Children,
                row.Baby,
                row.Start_date,
                row.End_date,
                row.Stays,
                row.Reservation_date,
                row.Property,
                row.Covid_payment,
                row.Charged_amount,
                row.Revenue,
                row.Email,
                row.Origin,
                row.Market_code,
                row.Transport
                )               
conn.commit()
```

I hope you can assist me with this and thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like one of your input strings can't be implicitly converted to the SQL Server `float` type. Have you tried using [cursor.setinputsizes](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#setinputsizeslist_of_value_tuples) to match your table's column's data types?

Comment: In which part of my script I should use this @AlwaysLearning? I am quite new in Python, sorry!